# Is it possible to create PDF from HTML in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf

I know it's possible to do that with PHP. But how to do that with AcionScript. If, i.e., I have ant HTML saved in my db, loaded to flash client, how to generate the PDF? 
There is a good open source library AlivePDF, but it doesn't have feature to generate the PDF from HTML.

any suggestions?

Comment: What data do you want from the html? Just the actual text or the layout and design (colours and sizes of text etc)?

Comment: exactly the layout and design :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you will get to generating a PDF with the exact layout of the html is to use a library like `Html wrapper` (http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/) to render the html and then use the `draw` method of the `Bitmap` class to create a copy of the `DisplayObject` the html is rendered in.

Then use the `addImage` method in the `AlivePDF` library to add the `BitmapData` from that `Bitmap`. Finally render the whole PDF with `AlivePDF`.

This way you will get an exact layout of the html, however everything is a static image inside the pdf. So you won't be able to select text and such.

Comment: thank, Ancide. I found that solution myself. It's worth looking for me, because that created PDF is used only for printing not for copying.